# конструкторы базового и производного классов c++

Tags: c++, ооп

Нужна ваша помощь

Как дописать конструкторы базового и производного классов для этой программе.

main.cpp

```
#include "people.h"  

int main()  
{  

    engineer st;  
    int menu;  
    string name;  
    SetConsoleCP(1251);  
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
    while (1) {  
      cout << "База данных жителей Украиныы\n";  
      cout << "===============================\n";  
      cout << "1-Иницализация данных\n";  
      cout << "2-Вывод всех жителей\n";  
      cout << "3-Выход\n";  
      cout<<"=================================\n";  
      cout<<"Выберите пункт:";  
      cin >> menu;  

       switch (menu) {  
           case 1:  
              cout << "Введите информацию о всех жителей\n";  
              cout << "===============================\n";  
              st.people();  
            break;  
           case 2:  
               cout << "Информация:\n";  
               cout << "===============================\n";  
               st.show();  
           break;  
            case 3:  
                exit(0);  
            break;  
            default: cout<<"Неправильный номер"<<"\n";  
       }  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

people.h

```
    #pragma once  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <conio.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h>  
using namespace std;  
struct ret  
{  
    string name_retraining;  
    int year_retraining;  
};  
class people {  
public:  
    string fio;  
    string birthday;  
    string pol;  

    //void info();  

};  
class engineer : public people {  
    public:  
        string ending;  
        string university;  
        string spe******t;  
        string typ;  
        string trainingtyp;  
        int retraining = 1;  
        string work;  
        int salary = 0;  
        ret *d;  
        //engineer();  

        void people();  
        void show();  
};
```

people.cpp

```
    #include "people.h"  

void engineer::people() {  
        double fixed_salary;  
        int working_days;  
        int days_in_month;  
        cout << "Введите фамилия:" << "";  
        cin>>fio;  
        cout << "Введите дату рождения:" << "";  
        cin>>birthday;  
        cout << "Введите пол:" << "";  
        cin >> pol;  
        cout << "Введите год окончания СШ:" << "";  
        cin >> ending;  
        cout << "Введите ваш вуз:" << "";  
        cin >> university;  

        cout << "Введите специальность:" << "";  
        cin >> spe******t;  
        cout << "Введите тип диплома:" << "";  
        cin >> typ;  
        cout << "Введите тип обучения:" << "";  
        cin >> trainingtyp;  
        cout << "Введите фикцированную зарплату:";  
        cin >> fixed_salary;  
        cout << "введите  рабочих дней:";  
        cin >> working_days;  
        cout << "Введите  сколько дней месяцей:";  
        cin >> days_in_month;  
        salary =  fixed_salary*working_days/days_in_month;  
        cout << "Введите место работы:" << "";  
        cin >> work;  
        cout << "Введите количество смены переквалификации:" << "";  
        cin >> retraining;  
        d = new ret[retraining];  
           for(int i=0; i<retraining; i++){  
              cout<<"Год переквалификации:";  
              cin>>d[i].year_retraining;  
              cout<<"Названия переподготовки:";  
              cin>>d[i].name_retraining;  
           }  
        cout<<"\n";  
        return;  
}  

void engineer::show() {  
        cout << "\nФамилия:" << ":";  
        cout << fio;  
        cout << "\nДата рождения:" << ":";  
        cout << birthday;  
        cout << "\nВаш пол:" << ":";  
        cout << pol;  
        cout << "\nГод окончания:" << ":";  
        cout << ending;  
        cout << "\nВуз:";  
        cout << university;  

        cout << "\nCпециальность:" << ":";  
        cout << spe******t;  
        cout << "\nТип диплома:" << ":";  
        cout << typ;  
        cout << "\nТип обучения:" << ":";  
        cout << trainingtyp;  

        cout << "\nМесто работы:" << ":";  
        cout << work;  
        cout << "\nГодовая зарплата" << ":" << salary * 12;  

        if(salary) {  
            cout << "\nЗаработная плата:" << ":";  
            cout << salary;  
        }  
        for(int i=0; i<retraining; i++){  
             cout<<"\nГод переквалификации:"<<d[i].year_retraining;  
             cout<<"\nНазвания переподготовки:"<<d[i].name_retraining;  
             cout<<endl;  
         }  
     delete [] d;  
     cout << "\n";  
}
```

Comment: Чтобы что? *(5 символов нужно)*

Comment: дописать конструкторы базового и производного классов для этой программе.

Comment: Вы для начала решите, что они должны делать... В вашем варианте это вообще структуры данных (все поля открыты), можно и не заморачиваться :)